# PDF scraping using textract module

Tags: web-scraping, text-extraction, pdftotext, pdf-scraping

I have a Node.js app that have to do some web scraping of online pdf.
This is a piece of code:

```
var textract = require('textract');
const util = require('util');

var methods = {};

var urls = [
    {year: '2016', link: 'http://www.url2016.pdf'},
    {year: '2015', link: 'http://www.url2015.pdf'}
];
var result = [];

const textractFromUrl = util.promisify(textract.fromUrl);


methods.download = function(req, res) {
    return extractText();
}

async function extractText() {
    try {
        var config = {
            preserveLineBreaks: true
        };
        for(let url of urls) {
            let text = await textractFromUrl(url.link, config);
            switch(url.year) {
                case '2015':
                    await extractTextType1(url, text);
                    break;

                case '2016':
                    await extractTextType2(url, text);
                    break;

                default:
                    console.log('Error: no switch case');
            }
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('catch block');
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use `textrack` package to scrape pdf.
When I run this app, I get:

```
catch block
{ Error: Error for type: [[ application/pdf ]], file: [[ C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\96710848773.pdf ]], extractor for type exists, but failed to initialize. Message: INFO: 'pdftotext' does not appear to be installed, so textract will be unable to extract PDFs.
    at extract (C:\Users\myUserName\projectPath\node_modules\textract\lib\extract.js:147:15)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\myUserName\projectPath\node_modules\textract\lib\extract.js:155:7)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:267:5) typeNotFound: true }
```

In the [npm textract module page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/textract), is written that **PDF extraction requires pdftotext be installed, [link](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html)**.

So I go to http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html and I downloaded and istalled **Download XpdfReader: Windows 64-bit**.

I try again to run the app using `node app.js` (`app.js` is the main file of my app) but I get the same error so I download **Download the Xpdf tools: Windows 64-bit**.

It's a zip file, I extract that file and then I try to install `pdftotext.exe` but when I double click on `pdftotext.exe`, anything happens.
I also try to install that using Administrator privileges. Nothing.

I'm using Windows 10, 64 bit.

What I have to do?

---

## EDIT 1

As recommended, I copied the `pdftotext.exe` file to `C:\Windows\System32`. Then I ran my program again and I have this problem:

```
catch block
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at extractTextType4 (C:\myUserName\projectPath\file.js:301:28)
    at extractText (C:\myUserName\projectPath\file.js:78:12)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
```

Do I have to change the environment variables?

---

## EDIT 2

My `C:\myUserName\projectPath\file.js` is this:

```
var textract = require('textract');
const util = require('util');
var utilFunc = require('../helpers/utilFunc.js'); // my lib
var postgreSQLlib = require('../middlewares/postgreSQLlib.js'); // my lib

// object of methods
var methods = {};

// object of pdf links
var urls = [
    {year: '2014', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_2_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2013', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_1_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2012', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_5_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}
];
var result = [];

const textractFromUrl = util.promisify(textract.fromUrl);

/**
 * Do web scraping and save info on DB.
 */
methods.download = function(req, res) {
    return extractText();
}

/**
 * Switch between different type of pdf file.
 */
async function extractText() {
    try {
        var config = {
            preserveLineBreaks: true
        };
        for(let url of urls) {
            let text = await textractFromUrl(url.link, config);
            switch(url.year) {
                case '2012':
                    await extractTextType1(url, text);
                    break;

                case '2013': 
                    await extractTextType2(url, text);
                    break;

                case '2014': 
                    await extractTextType3(url, text);
                    break;

                default:
                    console.log('Error: no switch case');
            }
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('catch block');
        console.log(err);
    }
}

/**
 * Save data on DB.
 */
function saveOnObject(vaccines, regions, map, url) {
    vaccines = map.shift(); // remove and return the first element 
    regions = map.shift(); // remove and return the first element 

    let promises = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= 21; i++) {
        var line = map[i]; 
        line.forEach(async function(value, index) { 

            // make the values uniform
            var vac = utilFunc.makeUniform(vaccines[index], 'vaccine');
            var reg = utilFunc.makeUniform(regions[i], 'region');
            var perc = utilFunc.makeUniform(value, 'value');

            // create json object
            var obj = utilFunc.createJsonObjectCov(parseFloat(url.year), 'Italy', vac, reg, perc);
            covDataItAll.push(obj);
        });
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

/**
 * Extract text to pdf 2000-2012.
 */
function extractTextType1(url, text) {
    var matrix = [];
    var map = [];
    var vaccines = [];
    var regionsTemp = [];
    var regions = [];
    var regionLength = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]; 

    // text to matrix
    var textArray = text.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        matrix[i] = textArray[i].split(' ');
    }

    // create vaccines array
    matrix[0].shift();
    vaccines = matrix[0];
    map[0] = vaccines;

    // create regionsTemp and values arrays 
    for(var i = 0; i < regionLength.length; i++) { // i index for regionLength
        var j = i + 1; // index for matrix
        var indexToRemove = 0;
        var numberToRemove = regionLength[i];
        var region = matrix[j].splice(indexToRemove, numberToRemove);
        regionsTemp.push(region);
        map[j+1] = matrix[j];
    }

    // create regions array (merge some elements)
    for(var i = 0; i < regionsTemp.length; i++) {
        var region = '';
        if(regionLength[i] > 1) {
            region = regionsTemp[i].join(' ');
        }
        else {
            region = regionsTemp[i].join('');
        }
        regions.push(region);
    }
    map[1] = regions;

    // remove \r char from map
    for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            map[i][j] = map[i][j].replace(/\r/g, '');
        }
    }

    return saveOnObject(vaccines, regions, map, url);
}

/**
 * Extract text to pdf 2013.
 */
function extractTextType2(url, text) {
    var matrix = [];
    var map = [];
    var vaccines = [];
    var regions = [];

    // text to matrix
    var textArray = text.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
        matrix[i] = textArray[i].split(' ');
    }

    // create vaccines array
    vaccines.push(matrix[0][1].replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, ''));
    for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        vaccines.push(matrix[i][0].replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, ''));
    }
    var meningo = ''.concat(matrix[10][0], matrix[11]).replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, '');
    vaccines.push(meningo);
    var pneumo = ''.concat(matrix[12][0], ' ', matrix[13]).replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, '');
    vaccines.push(pneumo);
    map[0] = vaccines;

    // create regions array
    for(var i = 14; i < matrix.length; i++) { 
        regions.push(matrix[i][0]);
    }
    map[1] = regions;

    // create values array
    for(var i = 14; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        matrix[i].shift();
        map.push(matrix[i]);
    }

    // remove \r char from map
    for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            map[i][j] = map[i][j].replace(/\r/g, '');
        }
    }

    return saveOnObject(vaccines, regions, map, url);
}

/**
 * Extract text to pdf 2014.
 */
function extractTextType3(url, text) {
    var matrix = [];
    var map = [];
    var vaccines = [];
    var regionsTemp = [];
    var regions = [];
    var regionLength = [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]; // array that contains the length of the regions (I need to correctly split the arrays)

    // text to matrix
    var textArray = text.split('\n');

    for(var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
        matrix[i] = textArray[i].split(' ');
    }

    // create vaccines array
    vaccines.push(matrix[0][2].replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, ''));
    for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        vaccines.push(matrix[i][0].replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, ''));
    }
    var meningo = ''.concat(matrix[10][0], ' ', matrix[10][1], ' ', matrix[11]).replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, '');
    vaccines.push(meningo);
    var pneumo = ''.concat(matrix[12][0], ' ', matrix[13]).replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, '');
    vaccines.push(pneumo);
    map[0] = vaccines;

    // create regionsTemp and values arrays 
    for(var i = 0; i < regionLength.length; i++) { // i index for regionLength
        var j = i + 14; // index for matrix
        var indexToRemove = 0;
        var numberToRemove = regionLength[i];
        var region = matrix[j].splice(indexToRemove, numberToRemove);
        regionsTemp.push(region);
        map[i+2] = matrix[j];
    }

    // create regions array (merge some elements)
    for(var i = 0; i < regionsTemp.length; i++) {
        var region = '';
        if(regionLength[i] > 1) {
            region = regionsTemp[i].join(' ');
        }
        else {
            region = regionsTemp[i].join('');
        }
        regions.push(region);
    }
    map[1] = regions;

    // remove \r char from map
    for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            map[i][j] = map[i][j].replace(/\r/g, '');
        }
    }

    return saveOnObject(vaccines, regions, map, url);
}

// exports methods
module.exports = methods;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the the file to `pdftotext.exe` to either `c:\windows` or `c:\windows\system32`.

Basically any folder which is added to your PATH. Then it should work

You can see in the source code

https://github.com/dbashford/textract/blob/078b3654b2f4e4f11a179714bd827a556fc1f64f/lib/extractors/pdf.js#L24

The code assumes `pdftotext` to be in path

[image: PDFTOTEXT path]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think I didn't understand.
I copied the `pdftotext.exe` file to `C:\Windows\System32`. Then I ran my program again and I have this problem: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` (I edit the main message with more details). Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you add the file `C:\myUserName\projectPath\file.js` to your question?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I modified the main message by adding the code of the file `C:\myUserName\projectPath\file.js`. Thanks for your help

Comment: You exception has `extractTextType4` function and your code doesn't? Also now it looks like your original problem has been solved and now you have code related issue. Running it through a debugger and see why you getting a blank value